# How can I declare my script to all of the list of tenants in a table on a modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I declare my scrip to all of the list of tenants in a table on a modal?

The script equation is doing fine, the bad part is it is only working on 1 tenant on the table,

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var id = document.getElementById("<?php echo $value['id']?      >");
    var previous = "<?php echo $value['charges'] ?>";
    rate = "<?php echo $value['elec_rate']?>";
    var current = document.getElementById('current');
    current.onkeyup = current.onpaste = function() {

        var number = parseInt(this.value);
        if(isNaN(number)) return;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (number - previous) * rate;
        document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = number - previous;
    };
    current.onkeyup(); //could just as easily have been onpaste();
};
</script>
```

And My Modal :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type = "hidden" class="form-control" name= "id" placeholder="First Name" value = "<?php echo $value['rate_id'];?>">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name </label>: <?php echo $value['tenant_fname']." ".$value['tenant_mname']." ".$value['tenant_lname'];?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location </label>: Stall No. <?php echo $value['stall_number']." (".$value['stall_floor'];?>)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">SUBJECT </label> :
        FOR PAYMENT OF ELECTRICAL CONSUMPTION FOR THE PERIOD FROM
    <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
    ,TO 
    <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
</div>
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">METER NO. </label>: <input type="text" name=""  class = "custom-input"></input> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">ELECTRIC RATE </label>: <input class = "custom-input"  value="<?php echo $value['elec_rate']?> per kWh" id= "rate" ></input> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PRESENT </label>: <input class = "custom-input" id="current" name="current"></input> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PREVIOUS </label>: <input  class = "custom-input" value ="<?php echo $value['charges']?> kWh" id = "#previous" > </input> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">TOTAL CONSUMPTION</label>: <span  class = "custom-input" type="" id="result1" readonly> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">AMOUNT </label>: <span value="" type="" class = "custom-input"  id="result" readonly></input> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I think THERE'S something WRONG with YOUR caps LOCK.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read through [ask] . There is no list shown here and doesn't appear to be any code other than html relating to your modal

Comment: Cant you just take time to read my code and help me? because im a beginner at php Please help.